# TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: web3js, blockchain, truffle, error

So basically I am just getting started with Truffle and I have created my first Solidity code, which looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract HelloWorld
{

function SayHello() internal pure returns (string)
{
    return ("Hello World!");
}

}
```

I then opened Powershell and ran the following command:  testrpc
Than I compiled and migrated my code using "truffle" compile and "truffle migrate"

The problems started occurring when I opened "truffle console" and did this, giving me an error at the end:

```
PS C:\Users\**\MetaCoin> truffle console

truffle(development)> var hw

undefined

truffle(development)> HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(deployed){hw=deployed});

undefined

truffle(development)> hw.SayHello.call()

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined**

truffle(development)>
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's async.

Try

```
> var hw;
> var saidSomething;
> HelloWorld.deployed().then(... hw = instance; });
> hw.SayHello().then(function(response) { saidSomething = response; }); 
> saidSomething;
Hello World!    <=== worked?
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Than you very much for the reply. I got an error when I reached this line: > HelloWorld.deployed().then(... hw = instance; }); which looked like this:

Comment: evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
HelloWorld.deployed().then(... hw = instance;});
                                    ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:181:10)
    at Console.interpret

Comment: I managed to improve it so it became: HelloWorld.deployed().then(hw = instance); with this error: ReferenceError: instance is not defined

Comment: HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance) { hw = instance; }); // instance is the name you give to the response from the deployed method.

Comment: TypeError: hw.SayHello is not a function

Comment: that is the error I get at: > hw.SayHello().then(function(response) { saidSomething = response; });

Comment: Sorry, I might be a bit annoying, I am just a noob testing the waters

Comment: That would mean that `hw` is not the contract instance we think it is from a previous step ... `HelloWord.deployed() ... ` You can `> hw` to print it and you should see the contract methods or something is wrong.

Comment: Nah, when I do that, everything seems to be OK. I het like a really long list: TruffleContract {
  constructor:
   { [Function: TruffleContract]
     _static_methods:
      { setProvider: [Function: setProvider],
        new: [Function: new],
        at: [Function: at],  but otherwise the only thing that stands out is : transactionHash: null,